# Envelope Matching Problem

Tags: probability

An absent-minded professor
was preparing, say, 10 recommendation letters and envelopes that are supposed to
send to 10 distinct programs, but he ended up randomly stung the letters into the
envelopes. Let X be the number of letters that actually match their corresponding
envelopes. I have to find the PMF  which i did which is
$$\sum_{i=2}^n (-1)^i.\frac{(1)}{n!}$$ n>=2 and 0 where x=n-1 however i have to find the expectation and variance for 10 letters should i calcualte probability from i=1 to 10 and then multiply by random variable or is there an easier way. Also, what about variance? Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445893)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (as so often) there is an easyer way to find expectation and variance.

Give the letters a number.

For $i=1,\dots,10$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if letter $i$ ends up in the correct envelope and let $X_i$ take value $0$ otherwise. Then:

$$X=X_1+\cdots+X_{10}\tag1$$

$\mathbb EX$ can be found by linearity of expectation and symmetry.

Also $\mathbb EX^2$ can be found on base of $(1)$ and then of course the variance is in sight as well.

Can you take it from here?

---

edit concerning PMF.

$$\Pr(X=n)=\frac1{10!}\binom{10}{n}\times !(10-n)$$

Here $!(10-n)=(10-n)!\sum_{i=0}^{10-n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$ leading to:

$$\Pr(X=n)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{i=0}^{10-n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Have a look at [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) for this.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think in this case $X_1 , X_N$ will be equal to 1/n which i am still digesting. For variance, we can do the same thing so both expectation and variance is equal to 1?

Comment: The expectation of every $X_i$ is indeed $\frac1{n}$. For variance be careful. The $X_i$ are not independent so you cannot take the sum of variances. Find the expectation of $X^2=\sum_i\sum_jX_iX_j$ and make distinction between $i=j$ and $i\neq j$. Also the link of JeanMarie can bring you further.

Comment: this makes sense, I got it, i know i will have to calculate it the way that you mentioned. I am new to probabilty theory so still figuring out some stuff. Also, does the PMF above looks okay. I have calculated using Principle of Inclusion and exclusion

Comment: It certainly "looks" okay but to be honest I haven't checked it (too lazy for that).