# Expected values for a sum of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, summation, expected-value

For a Bernoulli indicator, why is $$(\sum \sum)_ {i \in \{1,..n\} j\in \{1,..,n \}/i}E(X_iX_j)=n(n-1)\frac{1}{n(n-1)} ?$$ I've seen it here: [matching problem - find variance using indicator variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445893/matching-problem-find-variance-using-indicator-variables)

As an example: $$E(X_1X_2)+E(X_1X_3)+E(X_2X_1)+E(X_2X_3)+E(X_3X_1)+E(X_3X_2)=6\frac{1}{3}=2$$, but  this is not correct

Comment: Be careful -- in your sum you have $\mathbb E[X_i]\mathbb E[X_j]$, but in the link the sum is for $\mathbb E[X_iX_j]$. These are different when $X_i$, $X_j$ are dependent, as they are in the link

Comment: Of course $0\leq E[X_i]\leq 1$ for any Bernoulli variable $X_i$, and so your first equation cannot be correct, regardless of the specific values of $E[X_i]$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ (which you never specify), since you claim the sum is $n^2$ yet there are fewer than $n^2$ terms.  Regarding your remaining equations, I observe that $\frac{1}{3} \neq 3^2$.

Comment: Did some edits right now

Comment: @Michael's comment still stands: the expectation is still bounded by $1$, so the sum can't possibly be bigger than $n$. In fact, I can't even tell you how to evaluate $\mathbb E[X_iX_j]$ unless you give way more information.

Comment: $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent bernoulli variables

Comment: The problem is at the multiplication of these variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link, it is claimed that $$\sum_{i\neq j}\mathbb E[X_iX_j]=1,$$ where the $X_i$ are Bernoulli with parameter $1/n$. This result though is specific to the way that the $X_i$ are defined.

In the link (which essentially concerns fixed points of a permutation), when $i\neq j$ we have $\mathbb E[X_iX_j]=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. This is because $X_iX_j=1$ iff both $i$ and $j$ are fixed by the permutation; otherwise it is $0$. There are $(n-2)!$ permutations that fix both $i$ and $j$, and $n!$ permutations in total. So
$$\mathbb E[X_iX_j]=0+1\cdot\mathbb P(X_iX_j=1)=\frac{(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}.$$
The number of pairs $(i,j)$ with $i\neq j$ is precisely $n(n-1)$. So the sum evaluates to $1$.

This result though is false when the $X_i$ are pairwise independent (in the link the $X_i$ depend on each other). In that case,
$$\mathbb E[X_iX_j]=\mathbb E[X_i]\cdot\mathbb E[X_j]=\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
So the sum evaluates to
$$\sum_{i\neq j}\mathbb E[X_iX_j]=\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}=\frac{n-1}{n}.$$